# Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W automatically disconnects after editing and saving new code in the `code.py` file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero, adafruit-circuitpython

I have a question for you. Has anyone encountered an issue related to **crashing and automatic disconnection of Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W when attempting to edit and save new code in the `code.py` file**? I'm not sure what could be causing the problem, but it's preventing me from doing any work on the device.

After connecting the RPi via USB cable to the Mac and attempting to edit or save the code, the IDE freezes, and the cursor turns into a loading animation.
After a moment, I receive two messages and the device disconnects, requiring me to unplug and plug it back.

[image]
[image]

I've tested several different versions of CircuitPython (7.X, 8.X, 9.0), but the error persists regardless of the version.

Here's what I'm using:

- MacOS (I also tested it on Win 11),
- 32GB *Kingston* micro SD card,
- IDE: Mu Editor (also tested with Thonny),
- I upload CircuitPython to the memory card using *Raspberry Pi Imager*.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this, or could it be a problem with a damaged RPi?

Comment: Any Logs? Tried different OS? Automatic disconnection from what?

Comment: @TheMaster I tried with Windows 11 and Thonny IDE, but the results were the same. (I've added some imges with the messages I received, nothing more )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CircuitPython broadcom port is very alpha. See https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython/issues/8759 and related issues.

Comment: Installation of standard **Raspberry Pi OS** and **Blinka** has been a great idea. 
After that, I connected with my RPi Zero via SSH and everything worked fine. A code is compiling and the RPi board isn't restarted after saving any file.
Thanks a lot 